# How to download PDF on Android(Galaxy S3/4) from stock browser over https

Tags: android, mobile, iis-7, https, samsung-mobile

The download over https on a Galaxy S3/4 just shows "in progress" for a while and then eventually fails.

I created a new site in IIS7 with 2 files: "pdf.pdf" and "index.html". I've set the bindings of the site to static.local.com for http and https(self signed cert) and my host file points static.local.com to 127.0.0.1.

Contents of index.html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <a href="https://static.local.com/pdf.pdf" target="_blank">link</a>
    <a href="http://static.local.com/pdf.pdf" target="_blank">link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Only the http link works on the Galaxy S3/4. Also this scenario has been tested with a valid SSL cert. I see this issue posted all over the internet of people having issues downloading pdfs over https, but was hoping someone had a workaround that doesn't involve using another browser, download works with Opera-mini.

Answer (score 0):

I've not heard of this problem, if lots of people are having it, then it sounds like a nuance of android. One thing I would try in the meantime if you need a quick workaround is perhaps try setting different headers in the response for the pdf such as the content-disposition to inline, or content-type etc. [List of HTTP header fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)

Perhaps Android OS is trying to be "helpful" with pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

Checking your SSL setup would be the primary thing here. Self signed may not even stand a chance but for a CA signed certificate you need to make sure everything is proper.

Ideally, you would only need the certificate and the private key to include in your web server configuration. But, most of the commonly available SSL certificates are issued by an Intermediate CA and not the root CA. Hence, you are also suppose to include intermediate certificate chain on your web server to complete the setup.

However, things become complicated because most of the browsers try to forgive omission of intermediate certificate chains by downloading the intermediate cert chain themselves (based on information contained in your SSL certificate). Hence everything seems to work fine until you use a browser or HTTP client library which doesn't do that automatically.

Check your SSL setup here:
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/